# Search .attr/variable value with wildcards

Tags: jquery

fairly new to JQuery, this is easier to explain after you see the code.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr id="1a1">
        <td><div class="clickme"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="1a2">
        <td><div class="clickme"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="1b1">
        <td><div class="clickme"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Script:

```
$('.clickme').on('click',function(){
    var trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    // Stuck here
});
```

What I'm trying to do is when the clickme div is clicked, return the table row ID, check it and do actions based on its name.

So if it starts with 1a, do X, if 1b do Y and so on.

Comment: What's exactly blocking you ? Testing `if (trid.indexOf('1a')===0)` ?

Comment: [IDs **must** start with a letter](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name). `id="1a1"`, for example, isn't valid.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly it is in html5

Comment: You could use `var trid = $(this).parents('tr').prop('id').substr(0, 2);` to get the first 2 characters of the parent tr id, is that what you're asking?

Comment: @billyonecan in that case, if this is HTML5 then the table should have a `<tbody>`.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly please read [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/tabular-data.html). That's just false.

Comment: @dystroy from [the `tr` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element): `tr` can be contained within a `thead`, `tbody` and `tfoot`, and only `table` if it comes *after any `caption`, `colgroup`, and `thead` elements* - which isn't the case here.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly That doesn't mean that caption, colgroup, or thead are required for a `tr` to be a child of `table`, it just means that if they are there they must precede the `tr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var trprefix = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id').substr(0, 2);
switch (trprefix) {
    case '1a':
        // Do X
        break;
    case '1b':
        // Do Y
        break;
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
if(/^ia/.test(trid)){
    //Do X
} else if(/^ib/.test(trid)){
    //Do Y
}
```